# How to reshape a 4 dimensional Numpy array into different dimensions?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 4 dimensional `Numpy` array, of `(8, 1, 1, 102)`. Now, for instance, I simply want to ignore the middle two dimensions and have an array of shape `(8,102)`, what may be the suitable way to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you mean shape `(1, 102)` or shape `(8, 102)`?

Comment: @FHTMitchell I would like the reshaped array of dimensions (1,102). Thanks

Comment: I got your point. Sorry, I would like the final dimensions to be (8,102). Have edited my question accordingly. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't simply "ignore" the first two dimensions. You have an array of size `8 * 1 * 1 * 102 == 816` but you want an array of size `1 * 102` so you will have to choose which values to drop.

For example, if you want the first 102 you can do

```
array[0, 0]
```

which will have shape `(1, 102)`

## Edit

If you want dimensions `(8, 102)` then, as the other user who deleted their answer said, you want [`np.squeeze`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.squeeze.html).

```
x = np.random.random((8, 1, 1, 102))
y = np.squeeze(x)
print(y.shape)  # (8, 102)
```

Answer (score 1):

np.squeeze will collapse all the dimensions having length 1, or you can use the reshape function